# PostgreSQL: how to define ENUM type with custom emunsortorder values

Tags: database, postgresql, enums

Is there is a way to create ENUM type with custom order index. It is possible to update pg_type afterwards and set enumsortorder field to desired value, but the question is it possible to do during creation? E.g. something like

```
CREATE TYPE environment AS ENUM ('stage' 10, 'prod' 20);
```

Comment: Create a lookup table instead.

Answer (score 2):

The sort order is defined by the type declaration:

```
create type my_enum as enum ('first', 'third');

with t(v) as (
    values ('first'::my_enum), ('third')
)
select *
from t
order by 1;

   v   
-------
 first
 third
(2 rows)
```

You can add a new label in a desired position:

```
alter type my_enum add value 'second' before 'third';

with t(v) as (
    values ('first'::my_enum), ('third'), ('second')
)
select *
from t
order by 1;

   v    
--------
 first
 second
 third
(3 rows)
```

Read about [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) and [`ALTER TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html)

If the above is not sufficient use a map function, e.g.:

```
create or replace function my_enum_map(my_enum)
returns int language sql as $$
    select case $1 
        when 'first' then 100
        when 'second' then 50
        when 'third' then 75
    end
$$;

with t(v) as (
    values ('first'::my_enum), ('third'), ('second')
)
select *
from t
order by my_enum_map(v);

   v    
--------
 second
 third
 first
(3 rows)
```

You can also store the values used by the function in a table to make modifications easier.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My question was primarily about custom order indexes. However maybe it's a bad idea at all.

Comment: I think the function gives you what you wanted, maybe in another form. But it's not a bad idea, I used successfully a similar solution in one of my projects.